# Do we have 2 logical query processings, one with indexes and one without indexes?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, indexing, tsql

In the book "Inside Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008: T-SQL Programming" the behaviour of a sql query is explained. The following picture is taken from the book. I have some questions about the explanation.

1. How is a sql query processed when there are *indexes*, that is, *would this behavior change*?

My doubt is because I am a "teacher" and I would like to teach more details to my students.

[image]

2. This explains it in SQL Server, but I'm pretty sure it applies the same in MySQL, is that correct?
3. Do we have 2 logical query processings, one with indexes and one without indexes?

I want to make sure my explanation to my students is still correct when there are indexes involved.

Comment: Indexes only affect the so-called physical processing - the algorithms that determine how data is retrieved from storage and combined. There can often be many different physical processes that produce the same logical result, but with different efficiency.

Comment: Hi @Steve,logical processing (the one in the image of my question) 1) is always applied and 2) then physical processing follows?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Without context, its unclear what this is trying to described. It looks like this is describing an abstract logic model of a query. So rather than thinking of physical and logical as separate, consider them as different ways of thinking about the problem. The logical model is a simplified model the is good for when performance is unimportant and reasoning about the outcome of queries. The physical model around qury plans and indexes is important if you care about performance, and is much more complex, and involves a series of transforms and concurrent steps.

Comment: Do you understand what a query plan is and what a query operator is? And what level of detail do you want to teach to? Because indexes should become clear once you understand what a query plan is.

Comment: Wow, that diagram is actively bad for understanding the process.

Comment: @jwa, in SQL, the query (as you know it in the form of source code) is what is called a "logical" representation, in which the programmer states how to get outputs from inputs. This is executable as-is. There are (typically) no mention of indexes, and it isn't necessary for any table to even have an index. But when you submit the query to the database engine, it does not simply execute as-is. There are two additional concerns. One is that appropriate locks are applied for transactional consistency. Another is that the most efficient algorithm is chosen to execute the query. (1/3)

Comment: Different algorithms may retrieve different amounts of data from durable storage (like hard disks or even tape spools historically), and they may process data in different ways - this is the case even though the output can be the same. The database engine analyses the "logical" query and the metadata of the database, and decides what it thinks is the most efficient "physical" query plan - that is, a plan which is much more specific than the SQL about exactly how the data will be fetched and handled. (2/3)

Comment: When I say it's more specific, I mean it contains decisions and how locks will be applied (not important for single-threaded execution, but highly important for concurrent access in a typical production database), it contains specific choices about which algorithms are likely to be most efficient (which may not look like the logical SQL, but have the same output), and it may use indexes (either existing ones, or make a temporary one on the fly). Because these decisions are complicated but can usually be inferred mechanically, the engine makes the decisions instead of the programmer. (3/3)

Comment: @pjc50, I thought it was a mostly alright diagram for showing the logical evaluation order of a query. The only thing I thought was slightly out of kilter was how it placed Top before Order-by. Certainly it's a reasonable go at trying to explain the complicated nature of the evaluation order, if not completely perfect.

Comment: @Steve the concept of "logical evaluation order" for general SQL queries is a category error. A SQL query is a description of what data you want, not how to get it

Comment: @Caleth, some people believe this, and I accept that this thinking had some influence upon the design of the original SQL syntax, but I don't subscribe to the idea myself, and I think a great many difficulties are caused by those who do.

Comment: @Steve so e.g. when the query planner picks a merge join based on the ordering it gets from the index lookups, and that satisfies the `ORDER BY` in the result; doing two disparate steps is part of the "logical evaluation order"? I think that's what pjc50 means by "actively bad for understanding the process"

Comment: @Caleth, for understanding *which* process? You're describing the analysis which the engine applies to make decisions about how it executes the query. Nobody disputes that it does this. But it must still return the same results as if it had evaluated like the programmer wrote. And in the process of writing the query in the first place, the (skilful) practitioner understands the "logical" evaluation order. I really don't understand how an understanding of the logical evaluation order is somehow superfluous for the programmer - e.g. how would you know what names are in scope at each clause?

Comment: @Steve I dislike the term "logical evaluation order" because it has nothing to do with the *evaluation order*. You can have a model of SQL queries that associates each clause with a pure function on immutable data, but that *doesn't have* an evaluation order, and the query planner is within it's rights to come up with something totally different.

Comment: @Caleth, the query planner is only entitled to come up with something different insofar as it conforms to the logical evaluation. I don't understand what you mean by "doesn't have an evaluation order". If I specify a series of joins for example, clearly they have an evaluation order. If I specify nested queries or CTEs, they evaluate logically in a certain order. Why are all columns in a single statement not visible at once, if there is no evaluation order?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149726/discussion-between-caleth-and-steve).

Answer (score 10):

tl;dr: Query planners are a big deal.

In general, before an RDBMS backend executes a query,
it first plans the query.
There's more than one way to access the data,
and the planner evaluates some of those ways
to estimate which will be fastest.

---

> 1. How is a sql query processed when there are indexes, that is, would this behavior change?

Given a "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE ..." query,
by default the plan would be to simply tablescan foo.
This is no different from `$ grep ... foo.csv`,
requiring us to drag *all* the blocks off the
disk and into RAM so we can examine them.

Adding an index may offer a second access path,
if the WHERE conditional can be evaluated using just that index.
Retrieving < 1% of rows via b-tree index is quicker than tablescan.
([Some](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_key)
indexes cover more than one column,
handy if the conditional mentions multiple columns.)
Adding more indexes can lead to an exponential explosion
of access paths that the planner might consider.

So, "would the behavior change?"
Yes, it would. We might find good
[selectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_optimization#Cost_estimation)
and choose to filter a conjunct by probing
an index, rather than by resorting to tablescan.

---

> 2. it also applies the same in MySQL, is that correct?

Yes, if you look under the hood of any mature RDBMS,
you will find a query planner that examines several
access paths, estimates their costs, and uses the
winning plan to execute the query.

---

> 3. Do we have two logical query processings, one with indexes and one without indexes?

Much more than that.

Each time we add an index, each time we add a JOIN, each time
we add another condition to an ON or WHERE clause,
we multiply the number of potential access paths that
the planner might wish to consider.
There is an old and deep literature on query planning.

To better understand how *your* database operates
on *your* data, start habitually asking for EXPLAIN PLAN
steps and statistics. Create a table and then explain
a query. Add an index and explain again.
Then another index.
Then change the conjunct in your WHERE clause.

It's worth noting that plans are only interesting for
tables that have significantly more than a hundred rows.
And the distribution of values in your data will make
a difference to the plan, since the backend will try
to estimate the selectivity of each conjunct.
For teaching purposes we often manipulate just
half a dozen rows, but when examining plan choices
we need far more data than that, and it should
be somewhat realistic data.

Comment: I follow your answer no problem, but I would warn that this is very jargon heavy and I'd be surprised if someone who didn't already understand all the crucial things, could possibly follow it. For example, what is an "access path"? I wouldn't want to attempt the explanation myself, as there's icebergs in these waters.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. How is a sql query processed when there are indexes, that is, would
>    this behavior change?

That diagram describes a process for determining *what* data a given query will return. It has nothing to do with how SQL server will evaluate that query, the presence or absence of indexes don't change what data you get.

> 2. This explains it in SQL Server, but I'm pretty sure it applies the same in MySQL, is that correct?

It would be broadly similar. Afaict, MySQL doesn't have `PIVOT`, `UNPIVOT` or `APPLY` clauses, so those steps don't exist. It has other operators of it's own, that SQL Server doesn't have.

> 3. Do we have 2 logical query processings, one with indexes and one without indexes?

No. Indexes impact the overall performance of a query, by giving the query engine additional ways of accessing the underlying data. The query engine will pick a specific access pattern that it thinks is fastest.